# Wait for class to change in playwright

Tags: playwright, webautomation, playwright-python

I need to wait for API request to finish, which is indicated by `loading` class in one of the elements.
I can get the current class value with the following code:

```py
page.locator("selector").first.evaluate("node => node.className")
```

I know I can write code that would call that every 0.1s to in order to wait for the change, but I was thinking that playwright has some better mechanisms to do that.
Is it possible to wait for class to have a certain value? Something like that:

```py
page.locator("selector").first.wait_for_value("node => node.className", "desired_value")
```

Can it be done or do I need to write my own such functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [wait_for_function](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-page#page-wait-for-function). e.g.

```
locator = page.locator("selector").first;
page.wait_for_function("node => node.className === ""desired_value""", arg=locator.element_handle())
```

Comment: This returns an error: `TypeError: wait_for_function() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given`. I'm at latest version of `pytest-playwright`.

Comment: @Djent how about now?

Answer (score 3):

Another possible solution is waiting for the final selector.

```
page.locator(".desiredClassName").wait_for()
```